# SAS identifying singlets in by group not working as intended

Tags: sas

I am trying to delete singlets from a certain by group. This is my code:

```
proc sort data=have; by ID date; run;
 
data want; 
    set have;
    by ID date;
    if first.date and last.date then delete;
run;
```

To me this should delete all entries that have only have a single date within the same ID. But for some reason, not a single observation is let through. Based on my dataset I should have thousands of observations being displayed. I have used this before on other datasets without any trouble. I know this is not a lot to go on, but is there some mistake I am making that I am missing?

Comment: Show an example set of 4 or 5 observations that is not working. You are deleting observations where the DATE within the ID only appears once.  If the dates do not repeat then you will get no output.  What is it that you want? Did you want to keep the ID values that only have one observation?  Or perhaps those that only have one distinct DATE value?

Comment: I'd also double-check that it's actually DATE not DATETIME, DATETIME could easily have lots of 'same date' but not actually same DATETIME.  That's if you don't mean "one record per ID", which is how I interpreted this.

Comment: You are both right - I should have used first.ID and last.ID and not date. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing:

```
data want; 
    set have;
    by ID date;
    if first.date and last.date then delete;   *if this is the first and last record for that date, then delete it;
run;
```

What you want to do, I believe:

```
data want; 
    set have;
    by ID date;
    if first.ID and last.ID then delete;  *if this is the only record for that ID then delete it;
run;
```

However, this might not be exactly what you want - depends on your data. You also have

```
proc sort nounikey data=have;
  by id;
run;
```

That removes any "unique" records.